# ProgressDialog: Why?

Tags: java, android

I would like to bring up a Progress Dialog and then I put the following code in the onCreate method from MainActivity

```
ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Loading...");
```

But after that, I would disappear the ProgressDialog and then I put

```
progressDialog.dismiss();
```

But eclipse tells me: " Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method dismiss() from the type Dialog " Why? The Snippet is

```
if(check.isDeviceConnected())
        {
            sincro = new Synk(this);
            sincro.start();
            ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Loading");

            }
```

Basically I want the ProgressDialog disappears after sync so I think the progressDialog.dismiss () must be set out the }

Answer (score 3):

You need to capture a reference to the ProgressDialog:

```
ProgressDialog myDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Loading...");
```

Then you can do:

```
myDialog.dismiss();
```

This needs to be done this way because `dismiss()` is not a static method, and it must be called on an object. Conversely, `show(...)` *is* a static method, so it can be called directly. (without an object.)

Comment: Perfect, but if I want to make it disappear after Synk as I do?

Comment: then you would most likely make `myDialog` a field (if necessary) and call `myDialog.dismiss()` where ever you want to dismiss it. This may mean you have to use a `View.post()` or `Activity.runOnUiThread()` inside the thread, so that dismiss is called on the ui thread.

Answer (score 1):

use **ProgressDialog** this way

for Initialize `ProgressDialog`

```
 ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(YourActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
```

after initialize show `ProgressDialog`

```
 dialog.show();
```

for dismiss `ProgressDialog`

```
 dialog.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 0):

you should change to like this:

```
if(check.isDeviceConnected())
    {
        sincro = new Synk(YourActivity.this);
        sincro.start();
        ProgressDialog mydialog = null;
        mydialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Loading");

        }
```

then you have to put:

```
        mydialog.dismiss();
```